# Existence of Sequence of numbers $n_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

We have a sequence of eight natural numbers $n_k$ with k ranging from $0$ to $7$, where each $n_k$ gives the amount of times the number $k$ occurs in the sequence $n_k$. Find all such sequences.
I worked on this for a long time and didn't find anything meaningful. I'd appreciate any help.
Edit: What happens for sequences of lenght l- how many possibilities exist?

Comment: This is a more commonly known problem for $k$ ranging from $0$ to $9$, where the answer is 6210001000. I'll do my best to deduce the answer for your case too.

Comment: Do you mean numbers or digits ?

Comment: Related: https://oeis.org/A046043

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1: no solution

For 2: no solution

For 3: no solution

For 4: $1 2 1 0$

For 5: $2 1 2 0 0$

For 6: no solution

For 7: $3 2 1 1 0 0 0$

For 8: $4 2 1 0 1 0 0 0$

For 9: $5 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0$

For 10: $6 2 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0$

Proof of uniqueness for 8:

- Note that $\sum n_k = 8$.
- $n_7$ cannot be non-zero. If it were, it would have to be 1 (why?).
  Then there is an $n_x = 7$. But then $n_x$ and $n_7$ already sum up to 8. Assuming $x \neq 0$, there would have to be 5 zeros in the sequence meaning $n_ x + n_7 + n_0 = 13$, which is a contradiction. Assuming $x \neq 1$, note that as $n_7 = 1$, we have $n_x + n_7 + n_1 \geq 9$, which is a contradiction.
- $n_6$ cannot be non-zero. If it were, it would have to be 1. Then there is an $n_x = 6$. Note that both $n_0$ and $n_1$ are non-zero, as $n_7 = 0$ and $n_6 = 1$. If $x \neq 0$ and $x \neq 1$, then $n_x + n_6 + n_0 + n_1 \geq 9$, which is a contradiction. So $x = 0$ or $x = 1$. But if $x = 0$, then there are six zeros in the sequence. But $n_6, n_0, n_1 \neq 0$, which is a contradiction. On the other hand, if $x = 1$, there are six ones in the sequence. As $n_7, n_1 \neq 1$, every other number would have to be $1$. It's clear this is an invalid solution.
- $n_5$ cannot be non-zero. If it were, it would have to be 1. Note that as $n_6 = n_7 = 0$, $n_0$ is at least two. There is an $n_x = 5$. Assuming $x \neq 0$, we have that $n_x + n_0 + n_5 \geq 8$. But $n_1$ is non-zero, so this implies that $x = 1$ (otherwise the sum would be greater than $8$). Therefore, there are five ones in the sequence, but $n_0 \neq 1, n_1 \neq 1, n_6 \neq 1$ and $n_7 \neq 1$. This is a contradiction.
  Assuming $x = 0$, we arrive at another contradiction. As $n_0, n_1, n_5 \neq 0$, all other numbers would have to be zero. But $n_1$ has to be $2$, which then implies $n_2 \neq 0$, which is a contradiction.
- $n_4$ cannot be two (or greater). If it were, there would be $n_x = 4$, $n_y = 4$, $x \neq y$, but this leads to $n_x + n_y + n_4 \geq 10$ which is a contradiction.
- $n_4$ cannot be zero. If it were, there would be at least four zeros, implying $n_0 \geq4$. But then either $n_4, n_5, n_6$ or $n_7$ would be non-zero, which is a contradiction.

To summarize, we already know the number is of the form $ n_0 n_1 n_2 n_3 1 0 0 0$. We now try to determine where the four goes.

- It should be clear why $n_2$ and $n_3$ cannot be 4.
- If $n_1$ were $4$, then the number would have to be $14111000$. This is clearly an invalid solution.

Therefore, $n_0 = 4$. The number is of the form $ 4 n_1 n_2 n_3 1 0 0 0$.

- If $n_3$ were non-zero, then either $n_1$ or $n_2$ would have to be three. Summing $n_0$, 3, $n_3$ and $n_4$ leads to a sum greater or equal to nine, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, $n_3 = 0$. The number is of the form $ 4 n_1 n_2 0 1 0 0 0$.

It's fairly clear there is only one way to finish this.

Comment: Is there a proof of uniqueness for 8?

Comment: I'll try to prove the uniqueness for 8. The rest should be fairly similar.

Comment: Well, trivially $7$ must be $0$ and $4$ can not be zero, else we would have a contradiction, so all that is left to be shown is that there's no possibility with $n_6$ or $n_5$ not $0$

Comment: I'm not following why $4$ cannot be zero trivially, but I added the proof for you.